# Book recommendations for learning MS Project?

Tags: ms-project

What book would you recommend for learning MS Project?

Comment: Do you already know the basics of scheduling, or are you looking to learn both MS Project and scheduling at the same time?

Comment: I am interested in books that focus mainly on MS Project, rather than in books that focus on other topics but presents examples in MS Project.

Answer (score 1):

I used " PRINCE2 planning and Control using microsoft project" by Paul E. Harris. Excellent book as it teaches how to create a PRINCE2 Project from the beggining using MS project: 2 things at once!

Comment: Do you by chance have a link to the book you can include?  Thanks, and welcome to Project Management SE, the Q&A site for Project Managers!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference, I have looked it up on Amazon and found that there's a version for MS Projects 2010; http://www.amazon.co.uk/PRINCE2-Planning-Control-Microsoft-Paperback/dp/1921059370

Answer (score 1):

I found that the MS Project 2010 Step By Step book was incredibly useful.  It takes you through more of a tutorial approach.  I like this approach because you're not reading a textbook, you're actually working through a project that is already set up so you can learn as you go.

Here it is on Amazon.com

[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Project-2010-Step/dp/0735626952](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735626952)

Answer (score 0):

When I was "deep diving" into the inner workings of MS Project I found any of the "overview books"  like [Step by Step](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735626952) to be a good reference guide.  They helped more as a reference when I wanted some in depth understanding of a particular feature.  The other book that I really liked was [Dynamic Scheduling with MS Project](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1932159878)

I'll also say that Gary Chefetz's entire series on MS Project Server was invaluable to me.  In my mind, these are -by-far- the best books covering the features of linking across schedules and the features of using Project Server.  I have the 2003 versions of his book (there were only 2 back then) but it looks like he now has [several](http://projectserverbooks.com/books/index.aspx).  I would not hesitate to drop the $$$ for his books if I was doing anything with Project Server (and I wouldn't run a big project with MS Project without using Project Server...)

Final thought - build schedules.  Lots of them.  I really internalized things like Fixed Units and Fixed Time by trying to teach them and come up with simple examples that really pulled the differences out.  If you use Project to collect actuals and do "wave planning" where you update the schedule each week (or 2 or 3) then you really need to understand with a set of simple examples (not an actual project) how different task types behave across the different views and which views are better than others to make updates/changes.

hth!

Answer (score 0):

I found ms-project grate for presenting schedule information at meetings. But poor for helping with what numbers to use (estimation), providing feedback (tracking) or being updated (dependency analysis). Consequently it would provide a perpetual beautiful fiction of the project. The real scheduling was done using simpler and cheaper tools, as they got better answers with less effort.

Comment: Not sure this responds to OP, but since the question is closed, the point is moot.